# Issue with Integration Toolkit setSidebarVisibile

Tags: visualforce, javascript, consoleintegrationtoolkit

I am trying to run the following script in my Visualforce Page in my Developer Org:

```
<apex:page controller="SidebarTestController">
<!--<apex:includeScript loadOnReady="true" value="/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js" />
<apex:includeScript loadOnReady="true" value="/soap/ajax/29.0/apex.js" /> -->
<apex:includeScript loadOnReady="true" value="c.na30.visual.force.com/support/console/39.0/integration.js" />
<script type="text/javascript">

  var callback = function (result) { 
     alert('Testing');
     if (result.success) { 
  alert('Congratulations!');
     }else { 
  alert('something is wrong!');
     }
  };
     function setSidebarVisible() {

       sforce.console.setSidebarVisible(true,sforce.console.Region.LEFT,callback);
  }
</script>
<a HREF="#" onClick="setSidebarVisible();">SetSidebarToExpand</a>
```

It is relatively straightforward. I am trying to use the setSidebarVisible method discussed [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_setsidebarvisible.htm)... However, I keep getting the following console printout when loading the page:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Subsequently, I get this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: sforce is not defined

Is this an Issue with the Salesforce Resource? (Is this a Salesforce Bug?) Or do I need to fix something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL is probably being resolved as a relative URL (you provided no protocol); the error page can't be parsed as JavaScript, causing the first error. The second error follows: you never imported the correct JavaScript file.

Make sure you're using a canonical path on the current server (start with a leading "/"):

```
<apex:includeScript loadOnReady="true" value="/support/console/39.0/integration.js" />
```

Do not use server URLs in your imports, as they are not portable across orgs (e.g. between sandboxes and production).

Comment: Thank you! I think the version number (39.0 as opposed to 40.0) also had something to do with my problem.

Comment: @Rooster Yeah, 40.0 isn't available globally yet, so that might have not helped if you were using that. I didn't see it in your original question, though.